# What is similar to coordinate layout (like android) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I just want to give animation in my app like tinder to show profile description page. In android its default functionality in material design by using coordinate layout class. Any one know that how can I give the same animation in my application?

Comment: You have to customize on your own or you've to find one from https://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Comment: little ideas for brainstorming: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/201/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/

Answer (score 0):

> The main appeal of the CoordinatorLayout is its ability to coordinate
>   the animations and transitions of the views within it through coordinates

There is no layout type like this in iOS

iOS layout is much simpler and give you more control, what you need to do is working with some UIView and manipulate them through constraints since constraints layout work perfectly with animation

or if you want to make a separate things you can just add UIContainer and then add to it your UIViewController's

there is a simple tutorial for animating autolayout constraints:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/animating-autolayout-constraints/

Answer (score 0):

I think we can manage using auto-layout constraints,

1. create a view that you want to hide and show. Ex: bottomView
2. Give the height constraint to that bottomView.
3. Give the vertical constraint in between the bottomView and topView that you wants to move upwards.
4. When you show the bottomView then the topView will automatically move upwards or if you hide the bottomView then automatically topView will move downwards.

Thats it.